# Touch events not working on multiple Modal boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

i am trying to get Touch Events to function on multiple Modal boxes so that when you tap on a button to open the Modal box on a phone, you swipe to the left/right inside the modal box and you should get an alert box telling you which way you swiped.

I have tried to use

```
document.getElementsByClassName("modalSwipe");
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById("modalSwipe");
```

which of course is the right way to target multiple elements, but then the function stops working all together and no alerts show up.

I have recreated my problem with the entire code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/BappoloSlappolo/full/VwLMgzv) but here is a snippet of the js script and parts of the html that i suspect as the troublemakers.

I've been stuck on this issue for two days now and i'm beginning to question my intelligence. 
Is there a obvious solution that i'm not seeing here?

Thanks so much in advance!

```js
// i suspect that a part of the problem starts within the function "init()"
var lbl;
function init() {
  lbl = document.getElementById("modalSwipe");

  lbl.addEventListener("touchstart", startTouch, false);
  lbl.addEventListener("touchend", endTouch, false);
  lbl.addEventListener("touchmove", moveTouch, false);
}

var initialX = null;
var initialY = null;

function startTouch(e) {
  initialX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  initialY = e.touches[0].clientY;
}

function endTouch() {
  initialX = null;
  initialY = null;
}

function moveTouch(e) {
  if (initialX === null) {
    return;
  }
  if (initialY === null) {
    return;
  }
  var currentX = e.touches[0].clientX;
  var currentY = e.touches[0].clientY;
  var diffX = initialX - currentX;
  var diffY = initialY - currentY;

  if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
    // sliding horizontally
    if (diffX > 0) {
      alert("Left"); // swiped left
    } else {
      alert("Right"); // swiped right
    }
  } else {
    return;
  }
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<section>
  <button class='button modalButton'>Modal 1</button>
  <!--and the other part of the problem lies here with modalSwipe -->
  <div class='modal modalid' id="modalSwipe">
    <div class='modal-content'>
      <!-- no content for simplicity -->
      <div class='modal-header'>
        <span class='close'>X</span>
        <h2>Modal 1</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your Codepen, I noticed you use the same ID (`modalSwipe`) for your modals.

IDs should not be reused on multiple elements.

Instead you should try to use class names and find the active modal. You could do this by adding an extra class `active` to the active modal. 
Once you close the modal, the `active` class should then be removed.

Comment: Thanks blex! I reworded my answer

Comment: That is right Zack, that is because when i change `modalSwipe` into a class, it stops working. I have tried to put `modalSwipe` it inside the DIV's class attribute along with `modalid`.  I also change ` getElementById("modalSwipe")` into `getElementsByClassName("modalSwipe")` but it still won't work

Comment: `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of all the elements with the modal swipe class.
You'd want to also check to see which of those elements is the active modal.

Comment: Interesting solution! It kind of makes sense when reading it but i have no idea how to implement this other than adding an extra class in the html. are you suggesting that i make changes to the javascript?

Comment: A simple fix would be to add an extra class `active` to the class definition. When you show the modal, you would add the `active` class. When you hide the modal you would remove the `active` class.